# Why does my insertion sort function return None?

Tags: python, insertion-sort

I tried to implement insertion sort in Python:

```
def insert_sort(list):
    y= len(list)
    for b in range(1,y):
        value = list[b]
        a = b-1
        while a>= 0:
            if list[a] > value:
                list[a+1] = list[a]
                list[a] = value
                a = a -1
            else:
                break

li = [34, 55, 4, 455, 556, 33, 2, 54, 6, 8, 1]
l= insert_sort(li)
print (l)
```

But I can't tell if it even works because `l` always comes out `None`.  What's wrong?

Comment: Hint: count the number of `return` statements.

Comment: It isn't your actual problem but using `list` as the name of a variable in Python is bad style because that name is already taken by a built-in function.

Comment: Why do you need to return anything? It modifies the list it was given as an argument, so you can just print `li`.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, this is why the built-in `list.sort()` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @torek counted 0

Comment: thanks for all guys.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `return` statement:

```
def insert_sort(list):
    y= len(list)
    for b in range(1,y):
        value = list[b]
        a = b-1
        while a>= 0:
            if list[a] > value:
                list[a+1] = list[a]
                list[a] = value
                a = a -1
            else:
                break
    return list

li = [34, 55, 4, 455, 556, 33, 2, 54, 6, 8, 1]
l= insert_sort(li)
print (l)
```

Comment: I have got a return yesterday, but it was still no result. Today it is can operated! Thany you very much!